# Exponential fit on a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, histogram, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit an exponential curve on a histogram created from the variable y1_pt and then get the exponential's parameters. Problem is it gives me the following warnings:

OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
and pcov_exponential =

```
array([[inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf],
       [inf, inf, inf]]))
```

and the result is more an exponential fit which looks to me slightly random.. (see plot)
Does anyone have a clue as to what's wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from pylab import *
import scipy.stats as ss
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


df=pd.read_hdf('data.h5','dataset')

pty1 = df1['y1_pt']

bins1 = numpy.linspace(35, 1235, 100)
counts, bins = numpy.histogram(pty1, bins = bins1, range = [35, 1235], density = False)
binscenters = numpy.array([0.5 * (bins1[i] + bins1[i+1]) for i in range(len(bins1)-1)])
def exponential(x, a, k, b):
    return a*np.exp(-x*k) + b


popt_exponential, pcov_exponential = curve_fit(exponential,  xdata=binscenters, ydata=counts)
print(popt_exponential)

xspace = numpy.linspace(0, 6, 100000)
plt.bar(binscenters, counts, color='navy', label=r'Histogram entries')
plt.plot(xspace, exponential(xspace, *popt_exponential), color='darkorange', linewidth=2.5, label=r'Fitted function')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it helps if you provide good initial parameters (`p0=`) and bounds (`bounds=`) for `curve_fit`? See e.g. the last example in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Comment: Fitting an exponential function with least-square errors seems like it's not a good plan.  I think maybe you should transform these values into a linear thing by taking a log, then fit the curve, then exponentiate the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a minus sign in the exponential formula, hence the overflow. It should be `a * np.exp( - x * k) + b`

See the example at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Good spot, thank you. That did resolve the overflow, but now I'm left with OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated and the above plot with pcov_exponential being infinite. So, my problem remans.

Comment: It might be that your histogram looks more like a Poisson than an exponential, where the peak is not closest to 0 and density not monotonic. You could fitting a Poisson or doing KDE.